# Chern characters of elements in a complex, from Chern character of the complex and Chern characters of kernels and cokernels of the complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, derived-categories

$\newcommand{\ch}{\mathrm{ch}}$Suppose I have a two-term complex $E:= (E^{-1} \xrightarrow{d} E^0)$ in $D^b(X)$ the derived category of coherent sheaves on some variety $X$. Suppose I know the Chern characters $\ch(E)$, $\ch(\ker d)$, and $\ch ( \mathrm{coker} \, d)$. Does this tell my anything about the Chern characters $\ch(E^i)$ where $i=-1,0$?

Having thought about it for a while, it doesn't seem to me that this would tell me anything about the Chern characters I'm interested in, but perhaps I've missed something simple. The only thing I can think to write down is that $\ch(E) = \ch(E^0)-\ch(E^{-1})$, but I'm unsure how to relate back to the map $d$.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you add the same sheaf $F$ to $E^{-1}$ and $E^0$ (and set $d$ to be zero on $F$) this won't change $\operatorname{ch}(E)$, $\operatorname{ch}(\operatorname{ker} d)$ or $\operatorname{ch}(\operatorname{coker} d)$, but will change $\operatorname{ch}(E^i)$. This shows you can't reconstruct what you want from what you have.

Comment: @Sasha Nice, thanks